# Addig User And Role to my UserRole table - Never used column name is missing

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-binding, model, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add Role to my User and store the UserID and the RoleID in the UsersRoles table.

```
                var userRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("User");
                user.UserRole = userRole;

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                { //until this point, everything goes well

                    UsersRoles ur = new UsersRoles();
                    ur.UserId = user.Id;
                    ur.RoleId = user.UserRole.Id;

                    unitOfWork.UsersRolesRepository.Insert(ur);
                    unitOfWork.Save(); // At this point I have an Exception:
```

42703: column "RoleId1" of relation "UsersRoles" does not exist

But I don't know what is RoleId1 and where this is coming from...

This is the model:

```
public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string RoleID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

}

public class UserRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

public class UsersRoles : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I have in the context:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne(up => up.UserRole)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserProfiles)
                .HasForeignKey(up => up.RoleID)
                .IsRequired();
        });
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What are the columns available in the database for `UserRoles`?

Comment: @Nishan Sorry, Edited. It is in the code

Comment: Please check your database, and see what are the columns available there. Are you trying to create a 1-to-many relationship between `UserProfile` and `UserRole`?, in that case I don't think you need `UsersRoles` table. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: @Nishan Yes, exactly. I've found tutorial but that was for many-to-many but I don't need more roles for each user. So I would have 4 roles and every user has one role. So you think I would not need the UsersRoles ?

Comment: I've tried it without UsersRoles, but then in my controller the
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin,Administrator")]
is not working, so noone can access, even if the user's UserRole is "Administrator" or "SuperAdmin"

Answer (score 0):

what is it that you are trying to accomplish here. User and role relations are already available in aspIdentity